# Why does TeXstudio's autocomplete suggest missing commands like \microfarad, \microampere, etc.?

Tags: siunitx, texstudio, auto-completion

TeXstudio's autocomplete suggested `\microfarad` as a command so I attempted to use it but received an "undefined control sequence" error. There are easy workarounds (`\micro\farad` and `\micro\F`), but why does autocomplete think `\microfarad` exists if it apparently doesn't? I had never used `\microfarad` before because I didn't know it "existed" until I started typing in `\micro\F` and noticed the suggestion.

This appears to be the case for other commands like `\microampere`, `\microgram`, etc. I noticed the problem with `\microfarad` because there are shorter commands for the other units (`\uA`, `\ug`, etc.) but `\uF` doesn't exist either.

**Why does TeXstudio's autocomplete suggest these non-existent commands?**

I've found this problem on two separate Windows 7 machines, and strangely I cannot find an siunitx.cwl file on either machine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \SI{1}{\microfarad}\\ % undefined control sequence
    \SI{1}{\micro\farad}\\ % works
    \SI{1}{\micro\F} % works
\end{document}
```

Comment: Autocomplete has not the slightest idea which commands are defined and which not. Don't let the editor trick you ;-)

Comment: By the way, good example.

Comment: @Johannes_B You're right; I re-worded the question a bit to ask why autocomplete is wrong.

Comment: @Johannes_B some editors (and TeXStudio should be among them) have basic parsing capabilities (of course don't work with very complicated definitions), so your statement is not completely true.

Comment: @giordano I know, somebody told me that TeXstudio is even capable of learning new commands. I am not sure where the list is saved and editable and i also don't know after how many instances an item is added to the list.

Comment: Anyway, a [very old version of siunitx](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/3f8161abd67a5e9f203e02ed4229b0245453fe4a/siunitx.dtx) had a macro called `\microfarad`, perhaps TeXstudio completion table isn't up-to-date.

Comment: So 1. you checked the siunitx package in the auto-completion tab in the options editor and 2. yes, if you put `\newcommand{\microfarad}{\micro\farad}` in the preamble and save the document once, Texstudio should be able to auto-complete `\microf` (or even with less characters) after that.

Comment: @henry Yes, the siunitx package is checked in the options editor. I know I can create a new command, I'm curious why TeXstudio's autocomplete is picking up a non-existence command. And are there any other commands with a similar problem?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?  If it's a Unix-like (GNU/Linux or Mac OS X) try to run `locate siunitx.cwl` to identify the autocompletion file for `siunitx`.

Comment: @giordano I just updated the question. I can't file the .cwl file for siunitx. I've checked on two different machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is a bug of TeXstudio. The problem is that TeXstudio has auto-completion support for certain commands hard-coded in, most likely for performance reasons. This can be easily checked by looking at the `texstudio.exe` in a text editor and searching for `\microampere` (line 68436 in version 2.9.4).

So I would say this is TeXstudio's bug and you should submit it in their [bugzilla](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/). I think this is a case for many other commands, so you could also suggest general cleanup of the hard-coded lists of commands.

**Edit:** I checked the source of TeXstudio 2.9.4 and really, the file `completion/siunitx.cwl` contains `\microfarad`, etc. These files must then be compiled into the binary which is distributed.

Comment: You have [the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.9.4/texstudio-2.9.4.tar.gz/download), one doesn't need to open a binary file to find it out.  `\microampere` is in `completion/siunitx.cwl`.  What's strange is that that file is different from the one present in the [repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/siunitx.cwl).  It seems they have a repository but use something else as base to build the executable.

Comment: @giordano: I just checked the source code and edited my post as you added the comment. This is strange indeed.

Comment: I'm using TeXstudio 2.9.4 on Linux and I don't have any `siunitx.cwl` even I can check it in the Options/Configure menu.

Comment: @sigur: We are talking about the source code, though. See giordano's comment above containing the link.

Comment: @Augustin, yes, I know. I just said that I can not find any `cwl` file on my system containing `\microfarad` on it. So how TXS could suggest it to me?

Comment: It is hard-coded in the TeXstudio binary. Try searching for "microfarad" inside `texstudio.bin` on your system.