# Can suggested commands be removed from TeXstudio's autocomplete?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I know how to *add* commands to TeXstudio's autocomplete, but is it possible to *remove* them?

I thought of this in the context of [TeXstudio's suggestions for some non-existent `siunitx` commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/why-does-texstudios-autocomplete-suggest-missing-commands-like-microfarad-mi) -- it would be nice to remove them since those commands don't exist. (Yes, I know I could define those non-existent commands, but why add them if I don't need to use them? I might as well clean up the list of suggested commands instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really comfortable, but the following works:

For example the auto-completion of `\number` annoyed me because every time I wanted to type `\num` (from `siunitx`) it auto-completed to `\number`. To remove it

- find the responsible `.cwl` file. Either you find the command in one of the files in `~/.config/texstudio/completion/autogenerated` or its in one of the build in files of texstudio, which can be found at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/tip/tree/completion/

  The `\number` command from above was hiding in https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/tip/tree/completion/tex.cwl
- make a copy of the file and place it in `~/.config/texstudio/completion/user/`
- remove the offending command from the file.
- have fun with texstudio :)