# Is it possible to remove a specific command from Overleaf autocomplete?

Tags: overleaf, auto-completion

I'm aware of this post: [Can suggested commands be removed from TeXstudio's autocomplete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245603/can-suggested-commands-be-removed-from-texstudios-autocomplete)

However I wanna remove a VERY ANNOYING suggestion from overleaf which is
\frac{} instead of \frac{}{}. I've never used \frac{} before, since that wouldn't even work yet overleaf still suggest that outrageous and useless command which is extremely annoying when half your document are equations (doing a digital copy on some thermodynamics notebook).

Does anyone has a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Issues that are highly or even exclusively Overleaf-related should be addressed to the Overleaf helpdesk. Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll contact them. I'll still post then solution here if I'm provided by any, so future generations can fix the issue.